# Is it possible to download Bing Home page images that are showing behind the search engine search box in my Lumia 525 Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.1, pictures, search, bing, screenshot

I found some pretty images in the home page of Bing search engine when I press the right side bottom corner of my Lumia 525 Windows Phone(OS 8.1). I wish to download those images but I was not able to do that. I tried like this because we can download those images in desktop. Is it possible to download those images? or Shall we able to take a screenshots of those images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can downland the whole gallery pack from http://www.bing.com/gallery/